# How an Web App targeting .Net v45 is able to run in a machine which has .netv40 installed only?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

[image: Command clrver]

I have an Web App targeting 4.5 but when I have hit clrver command I could see only 2.0 and 4.0 installed on my machine.My Question how .net runs this web app locally ?

Comment: Those are runtime version numbers, they say nothing about the installed .NET framework version.  The runtime version matters to the CLR and the jitter.  Any 4.x framework uses v4.0.30319, framework versions 2.0 through 3.5 use v2.0.50727.

Comment: Okay. then I should say these installed version no are bit confusing.Thanks !!All it matters to the clr version which in turn decides the target framework and uses appropiate installed .net version on the system to produce the output.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Erm, hopefully clear from my previous comment that the CLR version does *not* decide the framework version.  If you want help with your *real* problem then don't keep it a secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Web App targeting .NET Framework 4.5 which uses CLR 4.0.

In the article "[.NET Framework versions and dependences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)" you can get more information about correlation between .NET Framework version and CLR version.

> The .NET Framework version number is incremented at each release, although the CLR version is not always incremented. For example, the .NET Framework 4, 4.5, and later releases include CLR 4, but the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 include CLR 2.0. (There was no version 3 of the CLR.)